# Spring MVC - Session Attributes - Should that be passed in all controllers as ModelAttribute

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc

Am `@SessionAttributes` for maintaining SpringMVC.

Say, `@SessionAttribute("user")`

Currently am passing the object as ModelAttribute in all the controller, which needs to use the SessionObject "**user**" like

```
Class controller{

public ModelAndView method1(@ModelAttribute("user")){ }
public ModelAndView method2(@ModelAttribute("user")){ }
public ModelAndView method3(@ModelAttribute("user")){ }
public ModelAndView method4(@ModelAttribute("user")){ }

}
```

Is this the only way??

or

Is there any other way? such that I can have a base controller, which can return the session object by just extending the the base controller.

Answer (score 0):

What I've been using in some of my projects is this:

```
String user = (String) hsr.getSession().getAttribute("user");
```

If you're looking for some sort of authentication I suggest you start using spring security or other authentication mechanisms that can filter out pages according to roles or authentication status.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your exact requirement is, but what about creating a filter/interceptor that reads the value from session and stores it in a ThreadLocal that can be accessed by controllers later

Answer (score 0):

The controllers that need to access `@SessionAttributes` you need to add the annotation as shown below.

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"user"})
public class Controller {
   .............
}
```

HTH

Comment: Thats fine!!! Am asking, should i repeatedly pass this as an argument everywhere??

Comment: No you don`t have too. But in my experience, for security reasons I have to because I don`t want to fetch data of another user. Session give me access to unique data for that user. HTH

Comment: Please make some sense